# How to automatically dot fill line in Math mode

Tags: align

I need to dot fill line in math mode even in `aligned` environment. I'm using `\makebox[width]{\dotfill}` but for presentation accommodations I want that dots reach the end of line.
I know that there exist `linegoal` to compute the missing space but I can't find how to apply this in math mode. Is there anyway to get the missing space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[8]\parskip 1\baselineskip
\noindent 
$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^7}}\Rightarrow 
                  \begin{aligned}[t]
                    f'(x) & =\makebox[.6\linewidth]{\dotfill} \\[1.5\baselineskip] 
                          & =\makebox[.6\linewidth]{\dotfill} 
                  \end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it seems you're interested in using the full width of the text block, you might as well use another mechanism to set the equation. Below I've used [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) as it allows for a `p`-type column that stretches as far needed to fill (say) `\textwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[8]

\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{~}X@{}}
  $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^7}} \Rightarrow$
    & \dotfill \\[1.5\normalbaselineskip]
    & \dotfill
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}

\noindent
\lipsum[9]

\end{document}
```